# Adding custom Spring Security filter on controller method using annotation?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, java-annotations

I have written a custom strong authorization server and libraries for integration called [PowerAuth 2.0](https://github.com/lime-company/lime-security-powerauth).

Currently, the developer who tries to secure the API call with it can use it as such:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/session")
public class AuthenticationController {

    @Autowired
    private PowerAuthAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody String login(
            @RequestHeader(value = "X-PowerAuth-Authorization", required = true) String signatureHeader,
            HttpServletRequest servletRequest) throws Exception {

        PowerAuthApiAuthentication apiAuthentication = authenticationProvider.validateRequestSignature(
                servletRequest,
                "/session/login",
                signatureHeader
        );

        if (apiAuthentication != null && apiAuthentication.getUserId() != null) {
            return "OK";
        } else {
            return "NOT OK";
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to simplify the work for the developer though, so that the code can look like this:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/session")
public class AuthenticationController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @PowerAuth(value = "/session/login")
    public @ResponseBody String login(PowerAuthApiAuthentication apiAuthentication) throws Exception {
        if (apiAuthentication != null && apiAuthentication.getUserId() != null) {
            return "OK";
        } else {
            return "NOT OK";
        }
    }
}
```

Principle (probably?):

- Remove the need for autowired authentication provider
- Replace the signature verification call with a custom request filter
- Bind the request filter to a custom annotation with parameters
- Inject the resulting authentication object in a method parameter

Since I am not strong in Spring, could you please provide me a guidance on how to do this?